# Futures / Success race

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I'm learning futures, and I'm trying to create a method that, take two futures as parameter
(`f` and `g`) and return the first future that was successfully completed, otherwise it returns `f` or `g`.

Some use cases to illustrate the behaviour of my method are :

```
Future 1        | Future 2         | Result
Success First     Success Second     Future 1
Success First     Failure Second     Future 1
Success Second    Success First      Future 2
Success Second    Failure First      Future 1
Failure First     Failure Second     Future 2 (because we had a failure on Future 1, so try to see what is the result Future 2)
```

So I created this method :

```
def successRace(f: Future[T], g: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
        val p1 = Promise[T]()
        val p2 = Promise[T]()
        val p3 = Promise[T]()
        p1.completeWith(f)
        p2.completeWith(g)
        p3. ????
        p3.future
}
```

And now, how can I know which one completed first ?

Answer (score 5):

The use case is the first successful completion:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def firstSuccessOf[T](fs: Future[T]*)(implicit x: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  val count = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger(fs.size)
  def bad() = if (count.decrementAndGet == 0) { p tryComplete new Failure(new RuntimeException("All bad")) }
  val completeFirst: Try[T] => Unit = p tryComplete _
  fs foreach { _ onComplete { case v @ Success(_) => completeFirst(v) case _ => bad() }}
  p.future
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

firstSuccessOf: [T](fs: scala.concurrent.Future[T]*)(implicit x: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[T]
```

so

```
scala> def f = Future { Thread sleep 5000L ; println("Failing") ; throw new NullPointerException }
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing]

scala> def g = Future { Thread sleep 10000L ; println("OK") ; 7 }
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> firstSuccessOf(f,g)
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@5ed53f6b

scala> res0Failing
          3.value
res4: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = None

scala> res3.valueOK

res5: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Success(7))
```

or

```
scala> def h = Future { Thread sleep 7000L ; println("Failing too") ; throw new NullPointerException }
h: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing]


scala> firstSuccessOf(f,h)
res10: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@318d30be

scala> 

scala> res10.Failing
value
res11: Option[scala.util.Try[Nothing]] = None

scala> Failing too


scala> res10.value
res12: Option[scala.util.Try[Nothing]] = Some(Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: All bad))
```

@ ysusuk 's answer is what `Future.firstCompletedOf` does under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `tryCompleteWith` method.  It can be called multiple times and only the first completing future wins.

```
def successRace(f: Future[T], g: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  p.tryCompleteWith(f)
  p.tryCompleteWith(g)
  p.future
}
```

Comment: Can you see this please ? http://pastebin.com/2yqDHN5t. With what I describe, it should return the future g because the future f fail, with your method, it tries to complete the promise with the future that completes first, but it doesn't care about if it's a fail or not.

Comment: The answer don't match the question

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the previous answer, still i hope my example will clarify it a bit further, so:

```
def successRace[T](f: Future[T], g: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val promise = Promise[T]()

  f onComplete(promise.tryComplete(_))
  g onComplete(promise.tryComplete(_))

  promise.future
}
```

so the first completed `Future` will set the value wrapped in `Try` (so, `Success` or `Failure`).

Comment: As I said in comment above, your implementation tried to complete the promise but it doesn't care about if it's a fail or no. See the pastebin in the other comment.

Comment: @user2336315 you are definitely right, this implementation doesn't care what is the result of first completed `Future` (`Success` or Failure`).