# Test that a scalatest futureconcept throws a specific exception

Tags: scala, future, scalatest

I want to test that my code which returns twitter.Future throws an IllegalArgumentException when a requirement isn't fulfilled.

I'm using scala test with an implicit conversion from twitter.Future to FutureConcept (similar to how ScalaFutures trait works but for twitter Futures)

But I can't find how it should be done!

I've tried the following:

```
whenReady(methodThrowingExceptionFromFuture) {...handling}
```

This throws the exception as a TestFailedException before reaching handling part so it doesn't intercept the exception as needed.
So I tried intercept:

```
intercept[IllegalArgumentException] { future.futureValue }
```

But same here. I think FutureConcept wraps the exception as a TestFailedException so I was thinking of unpacking the real exception, but surely there must be some other way of dealing with negative test cases together with scala futures?

Comment: The implicit conversion of futures to twitter.futures is taken from here: http://cjwebb.github.io/blog/2015/02/02/scalatest-futures/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer hidden in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925352/scalatest-assert-exceptions-in-failed-futures-non-blocking/25572204#25572204).  Basically, pass a `failed` projection on your original future to `whenReady` and kin.

```
whenReady(methodThrowingExceptionFromFuture.failed) { ...handling... }
```

Or to just test that an expected exception type was thrown:

```
methodThrowingExceptionFromFuture.failed.futureValue shouldBe a [MyException]
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correct it refers to Scala futures. Since we use Twitter futures there isn't any failed projection available.

Comment: You just need to implement the failed method. This is how it is implemented in Scala Futures: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L187