# Is it possible to use a fixed constant instance of Failure as Try[B] for any B without casting?

Tags: scala

While thinking about my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399126/how-to-best-implement-first-success-in-scala-i-e-return-the-first-success-f), I realized I ought to be able to write something like the following:

```
  val empty: Try[B, forall types B] = Failure(new RuntimeException("empty"))
  def firstSuccess[A, B](xs: Iterable[A], f: A => Try[B]): Try[B] = {
    xs.foldLeft(empty)((e, a) => e.recoverWith { case _ => f(a) })
  }
```

because a `Failure` is a valid `Try[B]` for any type `B`. Is there a way to achieve my "`B, forall types B`" in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Nothing` type since everything in scala is `Nothing`:

```
  val empty = Failure[Nothing](new RuntimeException("empty"))
  def firstSuccess[A, B](xs: Iterable[A], f: A => Try[B]): Try[B] = {
    xs.foldLeft[Try[B]](empty)((e, a) => e.recoverWith { case _ => f(a) })
  }
```

You do have to sprinkle in a few types here and there though (added type parameter to `foldLeft`).