# Parallel Computation with Scala Futures

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, future, scala-collections, futuretask

I have a Function that computes two sub-functions like this.

```
def someFutureMethod1(input: Int): Int = {
      input + 1
    }

def someFutureMethod2(input: Int): Int = {
      input + 12
    }

def method1(sx: Int): Future[Int] = Future {

      val future: Int = someFutureMethod1(sx)
      val future2: Int = someFutureMethod2(future)

future.andThen{
return future
}
future2.andThen{
return future2
}


}

Print(method1(10))


expected result:
11
23
```

I wanted to return the results as soon as First function calculated,
and Update or append to the same result when second function calculated.

The Second function is dependent on the first function.As soon as first function executed successfully It should return the result. and First function result is passed to second function to compute the second function.
If second function is computed then return the second function result alone.

Is there anyway to do this .?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: A `Future` has completed with a value or it is still working on it. One or the other. (Or it has failed.) I think the only way to get what you want is to have each `Future` modify the same `var` variable on completion. Very dangerous. Very bad idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Futures / Success race](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659406/futures-success-race)

Comment: Can't you use Scala async to get what you want?

Comment: May be even a Scala Task can be of help! https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html

Comment: Can you explain exactly why and how do you expect this update to happen? What if other **Future** was already using the first returned value when the second method finishes?

Comment: I have updated the exepected result

Comment: How do you expect the print to be executed two times?  What if the print did not finished executing when the value changed? Have you considered all the concurrency issues of what you are asking? - I think what you really want is to execute the same callback two times, one time for **f1** and in parallel execute **f2** and pass the same callback to **f2**.

Answer (score 1):

check this code snippet (there are function signature modifications),

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


def someFutureMethod1(input: Int): Future[Int] = Future {
  input + 1
}

def someFutureMethod2(input: Int): Future[Int] = Future {
  input + 12
}

def method1(sx: Int): Future[Int] = {
  val future1 = someFutureMethod1(sx)
  val future2 = someFutureMethod2(sx)

  for {
    f1 <- future1
    f2 <- future2
  } yield {
    f1 + f2 //add logic for your final output
  }
}
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question about returning the first result and then updating it with the second result.

Comment: i think in this code we are not returning as soon as it is calculating.We are waiting for second future to compute then we are returning .

Comment: @Learnis; Not so. `method1()` does not wait. It returns immediately, but it returns a `Future` which might / might-not have completed yet.

Comment: @jwvh The point is that this code doesn't return the result of method1 which is what the OP asks for, it only returns the result of method2.  It is unclear what "return" means in the question, but the idea is to return the result of the first method and then update that to the result of the second method once it is available.

Comment: @Tim; Agreed. This code does not do what the OP asks for and, agreed, what the OP means by "return" is not clear. In fact, I think the question's most recent edit has muddied the water even further. But `method1()` returns the sum of **both** `someFutureMethod`s wrapped in a `Future`. So did the OP misinterpret the code or just describe it very poorly? Hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you *could* do something like this :

```
implicit val ec = Implicits.global

  def someFutureMethod1(input: AtomicInteger): Unit = {
    Future {
      input.addAndGet(1)
      println(input + " after method 1. And maybe also after method 2, because who knows.")
    }
  }

  def someFutureMethod2(input: AtomicInteger): Unit = {
    Future {
      input.addAndGet(12)
      println(input + " after method 2. And maybe also after method 1...")
    }
  }

  val at = new AtomicInteger(1)
  someFutureMethod1(at)
  someFutureMethod2(at)
  println(at + " at any point before or after the futures, so a pretty random value.")
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  println(at + " after all the futures. Probably.")
```

I added all the println so that the code is ready to copy paste and run. It will produce different outputs everytime you run it, which should your clue to run and flee !

I wouldn't accept this code in any code base I manage, and I wouldn't even accept it for a POC. It's totally unpredictable. Basically, the 4 instructions in method1 and method2 can execute in any order.

Note also that it doesn't guarantee that method1 is executed first.

If it's needed, you can change the code like this to make sure the first future is resolved before calling the second method :

```
  //Fluff removed

  def someFutureMethod1(input: AtomicInteger): Future[Unit] = {
    Future {
      input.addAndGet(1)
    }
  }

  def someFutureMethod2(input: AtomicInteger): Future[Unit] = {
    Future {
      input.addAndGet(12)
    }
  }

  def theUglyMethod(at: AtomicInteger) = someFutureMethod1(at).map {_ =>
    someFutureMethod2(at)
    at
  }
```

Once again, please don't do that ! ^^

Comment: Do this is Fine What exactly i  want is returning the response partly.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: you are computing the method someFutureMethod1 and someFutureMethod2 right .?

In that, once method someFutureMethod1 computation is done give the result to called one and method someFutureMethod2 should compute his task and append the result to old result

Comment: Well, you can rearrage the method signatures however you want, at this point it's an implementation detail which you'll have to adapt to your own real case (which I suppose is not adding integers anyway).

Comment: i dont think rearragement of your code will solve the problem

Comment: Well, too bad then ! Good luck :-)