# In scala, how do you transform a list of futures into a future that returns the first successful future?

Tags: scala, future

All futures may be successful eventually (and some may fail), but we want the first successful one. And want to represent that result as a future. This future will fail if all the futures in the list fail.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20659406/1296806 and presumably others.

Answer (score 5):

As indicated the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#firstCompletedOf[T](futures:IterableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[T]])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]), `Future.firstCompletedOf` is provided.

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionnContext, Future }

def foo[T](f: => Seq[Future[T]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
  Future.firstCompletedOf(f)
```

Comment: The other answer says first completed may be failure.

Comment: Yeah, so that won't work. There should be a firstSuccess.

Answer (score 4):

[RayRoestenburg](https://gist.github.com/RayRoestenburg/6096365) returns the first successful one like so

```
def firstSucceededOf[T](futures: List[Future[T]]): Future[T] = {
    val p = Promise[T]()
    val size = futures.size
    val failureCount = new AtomicInteger(0)

    futures foreach {
      _.onComplete {
        case Success(v) => p.trySuccess(v)
        case Failure(e) =>
          val count = failureCount.incrementAndGet
          if (count == size) p.tryFailure(e)
      }
    }
    p.future
  }
```

The key is to understand [`Promise.trySuccess`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Promise.html#trySuccess(value:T):Boolean) completes the `Promise` only **once**. Here is a working [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/I1CgGjfUQAasrBvIqkKgqQ)

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util._
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import Thread.sleep

object FirstSucceededOfExample extends App {
  def firstSucceededOf[T](futures: List[Future[T]]): Future[T] = {
    val p = Promise[T]()
    val size = futures.size
    val failureCount = new AtomicInteger(0)

    futures foreach {
      _.onComplete {
        case Success(v) => p.trySuccess(v)
        case Failure(e) =>
          val count = failureCount.incrementAndGet
          if (count == size) p.tryFailure(e)
      }
    }
    p.future
  }

  val futures = List(
    Future {sleep(2000); -11}, 
    Future {sleep(3000); -7}, 
    Future {42}
  )

  firstSucceededOf(futures)
    .andThen(v => println(v))

  sleep(1000)
}
```

which outputs

```
Success(42)
```

If all futures complete with a failure

```
  val futures = List(
    Future(throw new RuntimeException("boom 2")),
    Future(throw new RuntimeException("boom 3")),
    Future(throw new RuntimeException("boom 1"))
  )
```

it returns the last completed failure.

---

Note `Future.firstCompletedOf` is [not sufficient](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FIvPpFKoTFebCGUtmezLHQ) as it returns first completed (as a success or failure) **not** the first successfully completed:

```
object FirstSucceededOfExample extends App {
  def foo[T](f: => Seq[Future[T]]): Future[T] =
    Future.firstCompletedOf(f)

  val futures = List(
    Future {sleep(2000); -11},
    Future {sleep(3000); -7},
    Future.failed(new RuntimeException("boom"))
  )

  foo(futures)
    .andThen(v => println(v))

  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

which outputs

```
Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: boom)
```

Comment: You can `Future { sleep(n) ; -11 }` w/o parens.